# SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS 12)Shortcut Key for SP_Helptext

Tags: sql-server, shortcut

How can I add short cut key for SP_helptext?
I tried **Tools>Customize>Keyboard** but unable to configure as Sp_helptext is not in list.
What did I Miss?

[**My screen looks as This image** click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGHKa.png)

Comment: Tools window, then Environment > Keyboard > Query shortcuts - ?

Comment: Thanks for reply Roger. I did not find query shortcuts screen. I have updated my query with screenshot for reference

Comment: The "Keyboard" on the left is expandable. It should be there.

Comment: left keyboard is selected and henche the respective right side form is displayed

Comment: There is a little triangle to the left of the "Keyboard" in the tree. Expand it by clicking on it with the left mouse button, the "Query shortcuts" screen should be there.

Comment: hahaha.. Yes.. Got it. Thanks a lot.. Silly Me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please expand Keyboard, which I missed

**Tools>Options>Environment>Keyboard>Query Shortcuts**